# I'm missing buttons and pull down menus in Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

I am missing the sizing buttons and pull down menus in Mail. It is a full window of the Mail screen and the wallpaper does not show.

How do I get back the regular view?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're talking about Mail on a Mac.

Since you haven't included a screenshot of the actual window you're talking about, I'll refer you to the fact that you can customise the toolbars in various windows within Mail.

To do this: go to **View > Customize Toolbar...**

This menu option relates to whatever window type you have active at the time.

For example, if you've got a New Message window active (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) and then go to **View > Customize Toolbar...** you'll be able to customise the toolbar within the New Message window.

Likewise, if you have the Viewer Window active (i.e. the main default window that Mail launches with) and then go to **View > Customize Toolbar...** you'll be able to customise that toolbar.